# Match and return a sub-pattern unknown number of times

Tags: python, regex

Sorry if this is a dupe, not very Googlable.

Suppose I have a string as such:

```
abacadaeaf
```

Notice that it consists of pairs of characters, first of which is `'a'`.

I want to return all matching pairs, like so:

```
('ab', 'ac', 'ad', 'ae', 'af')
```

I've attempted this:

```
import re
line = 'abacadaeaf'
result = re.match('(a.)*', line)'
print result.groups()
```

which produces `('af',)`. In other words, it only keeps the latest matched thing and throws away the rest.

What's the right way of doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall) here:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall('a.', 'abacadaeaf')
['ab', 'ac', 'ad', 'ae', 'af']
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I've been looking for!